# How to convert an php array in jquery like Literal notation?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am getting array in php variable and when I print this array it looks like:

```
Array
(
    [0]=>array(
                [lat]=>2.4354343
                [lng]=>6.43434343
                [address]=>united states
              )
    [1]=>array(
                [lat]=>5.4354343
                [lng]=>8.43434343
                [address]=>delhi
              )
    [2]=>array(
                [lat]=>2.4354343
                [lng]=>6.43434343
                [address]=>Mumbai
              )
    [3]=>array(
                [lat]=>2.4354343
                [lng]=>6.43434343
                [address]=>rajsthan
              )
)
```

Now I want to convert it like this in jquery:

```
var loc = [
    ['united states', 2.4354343, 6.43434343],
    ['delhi', 5.4354343, 8.43434343],
    ['Mumbai', 2.4354343, 6.43434343],
    ['rajsthan', 2.4354343, 6.43434343]
]
```

Comment: JQuery/Javascript is a client side language while PHP is a server side language. JQuery has no idea about php or what language is being on the server and does not care. So...to answer your question, you are probably looking for json_encode in php. http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: Did you give up or what?

Comment: Thank you everyone for help...

Comment: @AbraCadaver: I have done it through json_encode(). If you have another suggestion for me.Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure to always hav lat, lng and adress fields you can do this :

```
$array = array(
    array(
        "lat" => 2.4354343,
        "lng" => 6.43434343,
        "address" => "united states"
    ),
    array(
        "lat" => 5.4354343,
        "lng" => 8.43434343,
        "address" => "delhi"
    ),
    array(
        "lat" => 2.4354343,
        "lng" => 6.43434343,
        "address" => "Mumbai"
    ),
    array(
        "lat" => 2.4354343,
        "lng" => 6.43434343,
        "address" => "rajsthan"
    )
);
$loc = array();
foreach ($array as $values) {
    $loc[] = array(
        $values['address'],
        $values['lat'],
        $values['lng']
    );
}

print_r(json_encode($loc));
```

Answer (score 0):

Extract the values from each array and then JSON encode maybe?

```
$result = json_encode(array_map('array_values', $array));
```

Answer (score 0):

It's dubious why you want to do this as it seems like an unnecessary amount of work with no obvious benefits and possibly a number of bad side effects. For example, having a key by which you can access the `address` versus the `lat` and `lng` in each element of the array would alleviate the re-ordering requirement and obviate the cost of `O(n)` lookup completely.

In any regard, to encode this into the kind of JSON you're asking you'll need to run each element in the array through `array_values` which could be done with something like `array_map('array_values',$arr)`...

However, this doesn't solve your ordering problem of expecting the `address` part first in each sub array. To handle this you could replace the map with a combination of `array_values` and poping the last element off the array and returning the unioned array like so...

```
$arr = array_map(function($v) {
    return array_values([array_pop($v)] + $v);
}, $arr);
```

Finally the output of `json_encode` should give you what you expected...

```
echo json_encode($arr);
```

Comment: This loses the `lat` element in all arrays.

Comment: Yes, i accidentally ran both of your `array_map()` solutions.

Comment: Gotchya, edited the answer to inline that perhaps to make it more obvious that isn't the desired solution?